# How to set Sentence Case in a sentence using LotusScript

Tags: lotusscript, lotus

Question

1. String to be set:  **THis is A STring Character.**

Method

1. **properCase**

@ProperCase("THis is A STring Character.")
,

result is = **This Is A String Character**

The expected result i want is only a first character is capital letter.

**Expected Result : This is a string character**

**Lotus Script**

ok my lotus script that have'nt try yet

```
 Dim FirstDesc As String
                                Dim DescLenght 
                                Dim EndDesc As String
                                Dim FullDesc As String

                                FirstDesc =left(UCase(doc3.itemDescD(0)),1)
                                DescLenght = Len(doc3.itemDescD(0))
                                EndDesc =Right(LCase(doc3.itemDescD(0)),DescLenght-1)
                                FullDesc = FirstDesc + EndDesc
```

I can't find a LotusScript function with "sentence case". May i know is there another way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this examples will help you:

@Formula:

```
tmp := "THis is A STring Character.";
@ProperCase(@Left(tmp;" ")) +" "+ @LowerCase(@Right(tmp; " "));
```

Lotusscript:

```
Dim tmp As String, tmpResult As String
tmp = "THis is A STring Character."
tmpResult = Strconv(Strleft( tmp, " "), 3)+" "+Strconv(Strright( tmp," "), 2)
Messagebox tmpResult
```

Comment: sorry that is using formula, is it possible to use lotus script not lotus formula. Thanks

Comment: You gave your example using @ProperCase. That is formula.If you want help with LotusScript, show us what you have tried in LotusScript!

Comment: As Richard wrote you wanted a @Formula solution. But no problem at all I updated my answer with Lotusscript example and I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Strahil provide better solution~ My own Lotus Script update is on my question.